# How can we read or print all the values from drop down list of .xlsx file using apache POI java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am stuck here and tried everything to read dropdown list from .xlsx file. Please share some code which illustrate the things how Apache POI can be used

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you can try to work with [`getDataValidations`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getDataValidations%28%29) of `XSSFSheet`.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
try {
    wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("D:\\testWB.xlsx"));
} catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

List<XSSFDataValidation> dataValidations = sheet.getDataValidations();
Iterator<XSSFDataValidation> iterator = dataValidations.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = iterator.next();
    String[] explicitListValues = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jExcel API. It uses Apache POI and is really easy to handle:

net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12

you can try it.

```
WorkSheet sheet;

Cell comboBox = sheet.getCell(x,y);
String value= comboBox.getContents();
```

Comment: Will it work for .xlsx file?? As I am trying to do with .xlsx file it is throwing an exception "jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream"??

Comment: No, jExcel does not support the Excel 2007+ format.

Comment: Is there any way to read dropdown list data for .xlsx file format??